# Access to a defined property from static function

Tags: c#, static-functions

I would like to define a property in a static class, then access to this property from another static class. For this aim I have defined such a property:

```
public static class First
{
    public static void Run(string name)
      {
         xzFileName=name
         //my code here
       }
    public static string xzFileName
      {
         get
          {
            return xzFileName;
          }
         set
          {
            xzFileName=value;
          }   
       }
}
```

But I get an exception in this row `xzFileName=value`. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular reference. You're trying to set the property from within the property's setter, which causes an infinite loop.

Change it to use auto-implemented properties:

```
public static class First
{
    public static void Run(string name)
      {
         xzFileName=name;
         //my code here
       }
    public static string xzFileName { get; set;  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default behavior -**static classes can have only static members**. a static class cannot have any instance you cannot access the non-static members if there are any.

```
public static class First
  {
    public void Run(string name) => xzFileName = name;
    public string xzFileName { get; set; }             
   }
```